# Access issue accessing s3 selectively for application running under ecs. But works from CLI

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

When i access s3 through my code which is running under ecs. I can access only few files but for few files i get access denied exception. I have access to the bucket and the object are not restricted based on object leve;. i am using DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.

But the same files can be downloaded using AWS cli under the same assumed role.

Can help me understand what can be the issue?

Comment: Are there any details in the access denied exception that would help?

Comment: Are you using ECS Task Role to get to S3 or through `metadataproxy` utility?. which AWS SDK are you using for interacting with S3?